# Redux - Component not re-rendering using connect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a component that needs to hide/show content based on whether the user is logged in or not. My Redux logger is showing the proper state change but the connected component is not re-rendering. At first I figured it was a mutation issue, however after attempting the same thing with `immutable.js` and `redux-starter-kit`'s `createReducer` with no success, I figured otherwise.

It's my understanding that when using `mapStateToProps` the component should re-render the same as if it were local state.

**Reducer:**

```
export default (
  state = {
    hasAuth: false,
  },
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AUTH_LOADED:
      return { ...state, hasAuth: true }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**Component:**

```
class Screen extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {this.props.hasAuth && <Text>Logged In</Text>}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({
  hasAuth: state.auth.hasAuth,
}))(Screen);
```

**Root Reducer**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { batchedSubscribe } from 'redux-batched-subscribe';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reduxMulti from 'redux-multi';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import auth from './reducers/auth';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth,
});

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, reduxMulti, logger)(
  createStore
);

const createStoreWithBatching = batchedSubscribe(fn => fn())(
  createStoreWithMiddleware
);

export default createStoreWithBatching(rootReducer);
```

Comment: You set the `hasAuth` prop for `Screen` to be `state.auth.hasAuth`, but in your reducer you seem to update `state.hasAuth`, not `state.auth.hasAuth`.

Comment: Is this your only reducer? If not how does your `combineReducers` look like?

Comment: @Tholle the `auth` is actually my reducer name. I'm using `combineReducers` so it nests it one layer deep using the name as the property. I have access to `hasAuth` in my component, it just isn't showing the changes unless the component is remounted or I `forceUpdate()`.

Comment: @GeraltDieSocke updated the question with my root reducer in there. I removed any non-relevant reducers.

Comment: What happens when you write it like this: 
`export default connect(state => ({
  hasAuth: state.auth
}))(Screen);` in your Screen Component.

Comment: I'm not sure if the redux is actualy correctly wired up like this. What if you wire `batchedSubscribe` up like shown in the docs: https://github.com/tappleby/redux-batched-subscribe
Is it working then?

Comment: I get my whole state from that reducer: `{ hasAuth: false }` @GeraltDieSocke

Comment: @GeraltDieSocke I think you're right, seems to work when I remove all the multi-dispatch / batched-subscribe plumbing. Thank you so much, I was losing my head!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wire up Redux in Combination with `batchedSubscribe` correctly. 
Here are the docs with a short guide: https://github.com/tappleby/redux-batched-subscribe